# Google Maps time trace route

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

How about everyone.

I have a question on how to start using google maps. 
I explain: 
I'm doing a system where the position (latitude and longitude) of businesses enter and I have customers who also income the position (latitude and longitude) this is in a database, then suppose that there are four restauranes and I want automatically when I discharged my system assign a customer already restored more fences position.

I show an image as an explanation. 
[image: imagen 1]

[image: imagen 2]

[image: imagen 3]

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure I understand your question but here's a code I used to trace route for a set of Latitude and Longitude values:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA8lPDzcCN2E1icji4hSjmHgH-uFieMcX8&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
           zoom: 18,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.035307999999999,77.5688322),
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);

      var flightPlanCoordinates = [
   // set of (lat,long) values
new google.maps.LatLng(13.03545513,77.56844698),
new google.maps.LatLng(13.035312,77.56885567),
new google.maps.LatLng(13.03541774,77.56790266),
new google.maps.LatLng(13.0347358,77.56854116),
new google.maps.LatLng(13.0350667,77.56892307),
new google.maps.LatLng(13.03534067,77.56951356),
new google.maps.LatLng(13.03557602,77.56923249),
new google.maps.LatLng(13.03559478,77.56825478),
new google.maps.LatLng(13.03558727,77.5672599),
new google.maps.LatLng(13.03542425,77.5681003),
new google.maps.LatLng(13.03530649,77.5689072)
  ];

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);




      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
```

Comment: Okey said you better. 

If you see in image 1 are 2 markers yellow and 2 red markers, yellow markers indicate that they are (Family Network of 32 to 50 years) and red (youth Network 13 to 18 years) and the Scoreboard blue is the guest that he will map out where attending a youth network or if family network as the guest is 36 years old I want to get a radius apart from that guest as seen in figure 1 in this case there are 2 yellow markers within that radius invited therefore I want to know which arrives faster. 

Greetings. 
I hope I explained and check your code.